# Unable to make join in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

My table structure `'pages'`:

```
id int(11)
title varchar(100)
slug varchar(100)
order varchar(100)
body text
parent_id int(11)  (0/1)
```

I'm trying to join a table to itself so that i can get the pages having parents (i.e `parent_id` with `1`). I made this method in my page model which extends `MY_Model` but its not working

```
public function get_with_parent ($id = NULL, $single = FALSE)
{
    $this->db->select('pages.*, p.slug as parent_slug, p.title as parent_title');
    $this->db->join('pages as p', 'pages.parent_id=p.id', 'left');
    return parent::get($id, $single);
}
```

MY_Model:

```
public function get($id = NULL, $single = FALSE)
{
    if($id !== NULL) {
        $filter = $this->_primary_filter;
        $id = $filter($id);
        $this->db->where($this->_primary_key, $id);
        $method = "row";
    } elseif($single) {
        $method = "row";
    } else {
        $method = "result";
    }

    if(!count($this->db->ar_order)) {
        $this->db->order_by($this->_order_by);
    }
    return $this->db->get($this->_tablename)->$method();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you missed out **From** in your query

```
public function get_with_parent ($id = NULL, $single = FALSE)
{
   $result = $this->db->select('pages.*, p.slug as parent_slug, p.title as parent_title')
    ->from('pages');//here you need to put this code
    ->join('pages as p', 'pages.parent_id=p.id', 'left');
    return parent::get($id, $single);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

public function get_with_parent($id = NULL,$sengle = FALSE)
  {

$this->db->select('pages.*,p.slug as parent_slug,p.title as parent_title')

->where("pages.language", $this->uri->segment(1))

->join('pages as p','pages.parent_id=p.id','left');

return parent::get($id,$sengle);

}